# How to send a huge sized movie to a TV from a laptop?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, file-transfer, connection, tv

I own a Lenovo laptop Windows 10 built-in and a Philips Smart TV 7500 Series. I just wanted to watch a 4K movie on that. Never did such a thing so I need a small help in this case.

I've downloaded a 4K movie on my laptop whose size is huge (58.7GB) and I wanted it to send to my TV if possible. However, couldn't find a way to do that. I've been doing some research and what I've found so far is not quite what I want. Heard things like DNLA is required which also my TV does not support so I need to try other ways. I know that I could do it with a USB memory but I never saw one whose storage is above 32GB in my country.

Would be appreciated if you guys could help me on that. I really would like to watch some 4K movies on my Ultra HD TV. That'd be awesome and is gonna be my first experience about that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What inputs does your TV have?  What video outputs does your laptop have?  Do you know if the video output supports 4K and at what frame rate?  Does the TV connect to your local network (your cable/internet provider may use your local network)? Does the TV have built-in Chromecast or other streaming?

Comment: @fixer1234 I don't wanna stream, I just wanna send a 4K movie file to my TV from my laptop. "Does the TV connect to your local network?" Yes, it does. "What inputs does your TV have?" it has HDMI and my laptop also has HDMI but not sure if it supports 4K and what frame rate.

Comment: I want to send the file to my TV and play it from there.

Comment: If you have access to a 64GB flash drive, you could do it that way.  If you have a USB hard drive or old drive you can stick into a USB enclosure, that would likely work if it has only one partition and is formatted FAT32 (sometimes exFAT is readable; check the TV manual).  You would need to check the TV manual to see if you can send the file over your LAN connection.  Other than that, you basically need to play it on your laptop or another computer and output it on the TV.  (cont'd)

Comment: If the laptop HDMI can handle 4K @60 fps, you could use an HDMI cable to connect the TV like an external monitor.  The other choice is to stream.  That's really easy if the TV has built-in casting hardware like Chromecast (otherwise you'd need to buy a dongle for the TV).

Comment: Well, thank you very much for all your help. I assume I'll be looking for USB hard drives or a 64GB flash drive.